# How to create database on network hard drive?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-wireless

this how i try to create a sqlite database on network hard disk (seagate wireless)

```
    public DBControllerClient(Context applicationcontext) {
    super(applicationcontext,"smb://172.25.0.1/Public-01/Documents/NouveauDB.db", null, 1);
    Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created DBController");
}
```

Firt : can i do that to create db ?

When i try to see all data, i have this mistakes : file "smb://172.25.0.1/Public-01/Documents/NouveauDB.db" contains a path separator.

this is my logcat :

```
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     activity ComponentInfo{org.opencv.samples.facedetect/com.client.FicheClient1}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File smb://172.25.0.1/Public-01/Documents/NouveauDB.db contains a path separator
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2244)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5060)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File smb://172.25.0.1/Public-01/Documents/NouveauDB.db contains a path separator
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1992)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ContextImpl.validateFilePath(ContextImpl.java:1976)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:866)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:229)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at com.client.DBControllerClient.getAllClient(DBControllerClient.java:126)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at com.client.FicheClient1.onCreate(FicheClient1.java:370)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5146)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2156)
04-29 10:08:47.310: E/AndroidRuntime(4405):     ... 11 more
```

How can i do to solve my problem please ?

thx for your lights

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException`: File smb://172.25.0.1/Public-01/Documents/NouveauDB.db contains a path separator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android how to create db sqlite on wireless hard disk (seagate wireless)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220526/android-how-to-create-db-sqlite-on-wireless-hard-disk-seagate-wireless)

Comment: ^ Edit the original to contain additional info instead of posting new questions on the same problem.

Comment: ok i do it later but can you help me please ?